# \colorlet{saved}{.} inside \equal produces error

Tags: color, ifthenelse

`\colorlet{saved}{.}` inside the arguments of `\equal` produces error. What are the possible alternatives to `\colorlet{saved}{.}` or `\equal` that fix the problem?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
$\ifthenelse{\equal{\colorlet{saved}{.}a}{}}{empty}{non empty}$
\end{document}
```

More realistic example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\colorlet{linkcolor}{red!70}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=linkcolor}


\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{X}
{
  name={\ensuremath{X}},
  description={fg sdg }
}

\newcommand{\Xsubsuper}[2]{\colorlet{saved}{.}\ensuremath{\glslink{X}{X\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{_{\mathcolor{saved}{#1}}}\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{^{\mathcolor{saved}{#2}}}}}%
}

\newglossaryentry{t}
{
  name={\ensuremath{t}},
  description={fg sdg }
}

\newcommand{\tsubsuper}[2]{\colorlet{saved}{.}\ensuremath{\glslink{t}{t\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{_{\mathcolor{saved}{#1}}}\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{^{\mathcolor{saved}{#2}}}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent$X_1^3$\\
$\Xsubsuper{}{}_1^3$ wrong spacing\\
$\Xsubsuper{1}{3}$ correct spacing\\
$\Xsubsuper{}{3}$\\
$\tsubsuper{1}{3}$\\
$\tsubsuper{}{3}$\\
$\Xsubsuper{\tsubsuper{1}{3}}{3}$

\printglossary[title=Notation,toctitle=Notation]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add some background information why you use such a construct? Maybe there is an easier way ...

Comment: `\ifthenelse{\equal{\protect\colorlet{saved}{.}a}{}}{empty}{non empty}` but why??? it will always be false.

Comment: I want defined one command which uses `\colorlet{saved}{.}` and another command uses a check if its arguments are empty. When I insert one command as input to the other command I get an error.

Comment: sure but it would have been better to give an example using `#1`, as testing a literal string makes no sense. I sort of answered by adding `\protect`  but you can't do that in general and anyway the act of adding `\protect` makes the argument non empty.   I would simply use `\if` directly or a command such as `\ifblank{#1}` from `etoolbox` and avoid `\ifthenelse`

Answer (score 0):

`\ifthenelse{\isempty{\colorlet{saved}{.}a}}{empty}{non empty}` kind solved my problem, but I would be interested in other solutions as well. Especially solutions changing the `\colorlet{saved}{.}` rather than the `\equal`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
$\ifthenelse{\isempty{\colorlet{saved}{.}a}}{empty}{non empty}$
\end{document}
```

more realistic example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\colorlet{linkcolor}{red!70}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=linkcolor}


\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{X}
{
  name={\ensuremath{X}},
  description={fg sdg }
}

\newcommand{\Xsubsuper}[2]{\colorlet{saved}{.}\ensuremath{\glslink{X}{X\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{}{_{\mathcolor{saved}{#1}}}\ifthenelse{\isempty{#2}}{}{^{\mathcolor{saved}{#2}}}}}%
}

\newglossaryentry{t}
{
  name={\ensuremath{t}},
  description={fg sdg }
}

\newcommand{\tsubsuper}[2]{\colorlet{saved}{.}\ensuremath{\glslink{t}{t\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{}{_{\mathcolor{saved}{#1}}}\ifthenelse{\isempty{#2}{}}{}{^{\mathcolor{saved}{#2}}}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent$X_1^3$\\
$\Xsubsuper{}{}_1^3$ wrong spacing\\
$\Xsubsuper{1}{3}$ correct spacing\\
$\Xsubsuper{}{3}$\\
$\tsubsuper{1}{3}$\\
$\tsubsuper{}{3}$\\
$\Xsubsuper{\tsubsuper{1}{3}}{3}$

\printglossary[title=Notation,toctitle=Notation]

\end{document}
```